# Wordpress - Make search only search children of a specific page

Tags: wordpress, search, plugins

I have a Wiki section on my site, and I want to modify WordPress's native search to only search pages in this Wiki, or in other words, only children of page #278.
I've succeeded in listing children pages of a given page with wp_list_pages and the parameter 'child_of', so I've been trying for something like that. Two attempts so far:
In the search page...

```
<?php if ( have_posts(array('child_of'=>278)) ) : ?>
...
<?php while ( have_posts(array('child_of'=>278)) ) : the_post(array('child_of'=>278)) ?>
```

And alternatively in my functions file...

```
function SearchWikiPages($query) {
    if ($query->is_search) {
        $query->query_vars['child_of']=278;
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts','SearchWikiPages');
```

So far with no luck. If anyone knows how I can do this please help. I would not be opposed to using a plugin, or any other creative solution if it gets what I need.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your approach should work; the problem seems to be with using `child_of`.  I don't think it's a parameter `WP_Query` understands (it's not mentioned in [the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters)).

Replacing

```
$query->query_vars['child_of']=278;
```

with

```
$query->set('post_parent', 278);
```

worked for me.

Comment: Hmm - looks like `child_of` grabs all descendants, and `post_parent` only grabs immediate children.  May have to do it two parts - get all the descendants, then use those in your condition with (eg) `post__in`

Comment: Hm, what do you mean? Am I still editing the filter in my functions file? Just creating a variable that stores all the descendants of page 278 and calling that where I called set('post_parent',278) ?

Comment: Sorry, yes - still in the filter in your functions file.  Create a variable that stores all the descendants of page 278 (say `$descendants`), then use `$query->set('post__in', $descendants);` instead of the `post_parent` line.  Of course, if you don't have multiple levels of pages, `post_parent` should work fine.